# WebLogic script for changing the minimum password length

Tags: weblogic-10.x, wlst

How can I write a script to change the minimum password length to 4 characters using WLST

Home >Credential Mappings >Users and Groups >weblogic >Users and Groups >Summary of Security Realms >myrealm >Providers >DefaultAuthenticator>ProviderSpecific

How can I find the appropriate mbeans information to modify this using weblogic scripting WLST?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the path, you can navigate to the required MBEan and edit the properties as described here

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/config_scripting/nav_edit.html#wp1005462

Answer (score 0):

Bit late but this should do the trick...

```
connect('weblogic','weblogic','t3://localhost:7001')
domainRuntime()
edit()
cd('SecurityConfiguration/DefaultDomain/Realms/myrealm/AuthenticationProviders/DefaultAuthenticator')
print cmo.getMinimumPasswordLength()
startEdit()
cmo.setMinimumPasswordLength(4)
save()
activate()
print cmo.getMinimumPasswordLength()
```

Obviously the domain name, realm name and authenticator name will need to be adjusted to suit your environment.